# Background-image change not smooth

Tags: jquery, image, background, background-image, fade

I'm trying to fadeOut a div and a background-image, next change the background image and fadeIn new content and the new background.But image.jpg doesn't fade smoothly,especially when the image is very heavy.Any help?

```
$('.link').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()   

    $('.section1,.background').fadeOut( 'slow', function(){

       $('.background').css('background-image', 'url(image.jpg)').fadeIn('slow');

       $('.section2').fadeIn('slow');

    });  

});
```

Comment: You could use css trasition instead for the fading and jquery for the image swap.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4gddkuay/1/

Comment: I need 'display:none' that fadeOut use.

Comment: Hello mohamed,the image you are using is too light so it works good,but when i'm using heavy images fade is not smooth.

Comment: for that .. I think you can set all the background-image:  in css and end it with the last image you want .. to make it loaded before use click on link

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4gddkuay/2/

Comment: Thank you for trying mohammed but it does not work for me,I think a way could be preloading images with a plugin such like imagesloaded and then fadeIn content but I can't make it work.